# Data Source Error when sharing Excel Power Query file with others

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerquery

I have an Excel file that combines Excel templates from a sharepoint folder via Power Query.
On my computer this works wonderfully. However, as soon as I make the Excel file available to other colleagues, they can no longer refresh the data. After some tests I found out that in Power Query the sample file does not point to the right place. Is there a way how I can parameterize the part and fix the sample file that way?

Comment: It is possible, e.g., to store the path in a cell and refer to it in PQ. This comes handy if you keep the file’s own path as a dynamic reference in the cell, so PQ can always access to its own folder location (incl. sub folders) for sources.

Comment: AFAIK, SharePoint uses different types of URL path references (absolute vs relative), so you may need to take this into consideration when sharing the URL. More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/urls-and-tokens-in-sharepoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In excel, pick a cell and give it a range name, like NameVariable

Enter your filepath like **C:\temp\samplefile.xlsx** in that named range

Then in powerquery, in home ... advanced editor ... add a formula that refers to that range name, similar to this:

```
Location = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="NameVariable"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
```

and change any hard coded references to the filename to use Location instead

As an example, change

```
let Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\temp\samplefile.xlsx"), null, true),
```

to be

```
let Location = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="NameVariable"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(Location), null, true),
```

or if the range just had location instead of full filepath, then

```
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(Location&"samplefile.xlsx"), null, true),
```

Comment: Many thanks to all the answers. Issue is solved now. :)